# Delete a horizontal bar in an 'A' character in Glyphs

Tags: typography, glyphs

[image]

I'm trying to delete that horizontal bar using [Glyphs](http://glyphsapp.com). I can delete the four points that create it, but have no way of joining the inner points back up again.

I've been trawling through the meager documentation for hours.

Comment: It seems to me that the thing to do would be to delete the triangular counter entirely, then add a point in the middle of the crossbar and move that to the place where the top-point of the counter was. [I can make this an answer if it works!]

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yeah, it's what I decided to do in the end. Make it an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the points form part of the **outline**, it's not easy to remove the cross-bar. That part of the letter is formed by two different outline lines.

So: remove the line defining the triangular counter, and then add a point in the centre of the cross-bar and drag that to where the top-point of the counter was.

Answer (score 2):

Select the rightmost two nodes of the crossbar, rightclick and choose reconnect nodes from the context menu. Do the same for leftmost two nodes.

This is described in the tutorial videos and the handbook.

Comment: Does reconnecting those nodes keep them there? If the original four nodes which define that edge of the stroke are not completely in line, there may be corners in it (And that can also apply to my method too). Is it possible to remove the four nodes completely?